# Why [MnCl6]^2- has got 4 unpaired electrons instead of 3?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

In $\ce{[MnCl_6]}^{2-}$, $\ce{Mn}$ has +4 oxidation state which gives it a $\ce{3d^3}$  $\ce{4s^0}$ configuration. But how is it having 4 unpaired electrons?

Comment: @DhrubaBanerjee You can also visit ‎[this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/443/should-we-correct-math-‎formatting) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111/formatting-‎sandbox-please-test-stuff-here)  ‎for a better tutorial.

Comment: are you sure it was 2- , I mean the charge can be 3- on the complex.

Comment: The complex you are asking about has an odd number of electrons, there is no way it can have four unpaired electrons. With three unpaired electrons it is in a quartet state though. Can you refer us to the source of your doubts, maybe it is a typo in a textbook.